# React Native: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: react-native

> \android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:61: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_notif (aka ...:mipmap/ic_notif) not found.
>
> error: failed processing manifest.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.
>
> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.melkana">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
            android:name=".MainApplication"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                   android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notif"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                   android:value="my_default_channel"/>

        <service android:name="com.evollu.react.fcm.MessagingService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name="com.evollu.react.fcm.InstanceIdService" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyAYdeHDHPzBsliCXiPMScp-Jv_LOR3e98M"/>
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
        >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that helped me. For anyone having this issue go to all of four **`android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-(hdpi/mdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi)`** , make a copy of `ic_launcher` and rename it to `ic_notif`.

[image]